# Save Certain Map Annotations as Favorites, Then Display Them

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I've been struggling with this for days and am getting nowhere.

I have a mapView with approximately 60 annotations.  When the User touches a annotation, the annotation details appear along with a right-hand callout bubble.  If the User touches the callout bubble, a UIAlert appears, asking if the User wants to save the annotation as a "favorite" (all code works to this point).

What I want to do next is save this annotation as a favorite within the app somehow.  I then want the User to be able to clear the mapView of all annotations and display only the saved "favorites" with a button touch.

I'm at a complete loss for how to proceed and am asking for some help of what I need to do to accomplish both.  I'm using Xcode v6.1.1.

Some sample code:

```
//** Set map starting region and display two of 60 annotations **
    MKCoordinateRegion regionStart = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
    regionStart.center.latitude = 45.526197;
    regionStart.center.longitude = -122.675212;
    regionStart.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    regionStart.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    [mapView setRegion:regionStart animated:YES];

    [mapView setDelegate:self];

    //** Data for Acme Widgets **
    MKCoordinateRegion region1 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
    region1.center.latitude = 45.5262223;
    region1.center.longitude = -122.63642379999999;
    [mapView setRegion:region1 animated:YES];

    DisplayMap *ann1 = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];

    ann1.title = @"Acme Widgets";
    ann1.subtitle = @"1234 Main Street";
    ann1.coordinate = region1.center;
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:ann1];

    //** Data for Mike's Garage **
    MKCoordinateRegion region2 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
    region2.center.latitude = 45.5337167;
    region2.center.longitude = -122.6917036;
    [mapView setRegion:region2 animated:YES];

    DisplayMap *ann2 = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];
    ann2.title = @"Mike's Garage";
    ann2.subtitle = @"234 East Center Street";
    ann2.coordinate = region2.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann2];


-(void)saveAsFavorite{
    //** Displays UIAlertView when callout bubble on annotation is touched **
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Save As Favorite?"
                                                   message: @""
                                                  delegate: self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",nil];

    [alert setTag:1];
    [alert show];

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    //** Test for which UIAlertView button is touched **
    if (buttonIndex==0) {
        NSLog(@"The Cancel button was touched");
    }
    else{
        //** I want to be able to somehow note this annotation as a "favorite" **
        NSLog(@"The YES button was touched");
        }
}

-(void)clearAllAnnotations{
   //** Clear all map annotations **
   [self.mapView removeAnnotations:[self.mapView annotations]];
}

-(IBAction)showFavorites:(UIButton *)sender{
//** Need to add code for displaying only "favorite" annotations here **
}
```

Comment: By `favorite` do you mean a `favorite` from within your app? as in specific to it?

Comment: Yes, save the favorite annotations with the app.

Comment: You'll likey want to use [standardUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html)

Comment: Thanks.  Any chance you can provide a few lines of code that shows how to actually save a annotation?  That's part of the problem I'm struggling with.